# C++ function's variadic template deduction fails with MSVC, succeeds with Clang

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The following is a condensed (and slightly contrived) reproducible example of something else I'm trying to do to create a real-world convenience function. Basically, I'd like to be able to simplify function calls to functions with a particular signature, but which may have other, arbitrary preceding arguments before the final, conventional arguments.

Consider a function that returns a result via an `int&` as its final argument. For example:

```cpp
void SimpleValue(int &output)
{
    output = 42;
}

void AddTwoValues(int a, int b, int &output)
{
    output = a + b;
}
```

Functions of a similar nature could take any arguments before the final `output`, and use them to compute the output. They should always contain the final output argument, and should always (for the purposes of this example) return `void`.

I can create a C++ templated alias for functions of this type:

```cpp
template <typename... ARGS>
using FuncType = void (*)(ARGS... args, int &output);
```

Then if I wanted to write a convenience function to print the output of any of this family of functions, I could write:

```cpp
// Ignoring forwarding for the sake of clarity.
// I've also tested using std::forward and it
// does not affect the context of this question.
template <typename... ARGS>
void Print(FuncType<ARGS...> func, ARGS... args)
{
    int output = 0;
    func(args..., output);

    std::cout << "Computed output: " << output << std::endl;
}
```

The problem comes when calling `Print()`. Using Clang on Replit, I can write the following:

```cpp
Print(&SimpleValue);
Print(&AddTwoValues, 3, 4)
```

And get the expected output:

```
Computed output: 42
Computed output: 7
```

However, MSVC on Windows does not compile this code. I get the error:

```
error C2784: 'void Print(void (__cdecl *)(ARGS...,int &),ARGS...)': could not deduce template argument
  for 'void (__cdecl *)(ARGS...,int &)'
  from 'void (__cdecl *)(int,int,int &)'
```

I don't often consider myself smarter than a compiler, but given that template pattern and signature, even I could deduce those arguments, and so apparently can Clang.

If I manually supply the arguments, MSVC does accept the second function call:

```cpp
Print<int,int>(&AddTwoValues, 3, 4)
```

However, to get the first one to work, I have to define an overload of `Print()` for functions which do not take any arguments before `output`.

Is this a bug with MSVC? I don't understand why it can't deduce the arguments properly under these circumstances.

Comment: Might want to consider rewriting the question to include the complete program instead of piecemeal sections.

Comment: @n.m. That tweak is exactly what I need, thank you! Also I'll use Godbolt next time, it looks much more flexible for testing different compilers than Replit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Independently of which compiler is correct, there is no point in having `FuncType`. You can simply accept any type as the callable. Then it doesn't even have to be a function pointer:

```
template <typename F, typename... ARGS>
void Print(F func, ARGS... args)
{
    int output = 0;
    func(args..., output);

    std::cout << "Computed output: " << output << std::endl;
}
```

And if you want to make sure that the function will not be chosen in overload resolution if `func` can't actually be called this way, then you can add a constraint (assuming C++20 here):

```
template <typename F, typename... ARGS>
void Print(F func, ARGS... args)
requires requires { func(args..., std::decltype<int&>()); }
{
    int output = 0;
    func(args..., output);

    std::cout << "Computed output: " << output << std::endl;
}
```

(If you like you can also add perfect-forwarding by replacing `ARGS...` with `ARGS&&...` and `args...` with `std::forward<ARGS>(args)...` everywhere. The same can be done with `F` and `func`. Instead of a direct function call you could also use `std::invoke` to make it work even more generally, e.g. with member function pointers.)

Comment: Nice - this would definitely work for me, but the snippet mentioned in an earlier comment (https://godbolt.org/z/r45n9W9ac) is more concise for my particular use case. I'm using C++11 and need to be really specific about what it is that's being called, so that would probably work better than passing a generic callable. I'll definitely accept this as the answer though, because it covers all bases.

Comment: @NoodleCollie That isn't actually any different from my approach. The default template argument in that snippet is unused. `F` is still being deduced to any type you pass. Why exactly is it important what type the callable is? You can restrict the type with either `requires` clauses in C++20 or SFINAE before that, but I doubt that you really want to be as restrictive as in your question. For example, why does the function not allow callables that take references? Why does `Print` need to take arguments by-value instead of by-reference? Why are implicit conversions not acceptable? Etc.

Comment: Yep sorry, just tried to edit my comment and it crossed the edit threshold. You're correct.